# Pushing apps remotely from server to user's device

Tags: android, ios, remote-server, application-management

I have an application which runs on an organization's server. I also have a mobile application which the users of the organization can download from the app store.

I want the person managing the application on the server side to be able to select the users and install the mobile application remotely on the user's devices without users having to go to the store to download it.

How do I do this for my iOS app and is it possible to do this for Android apps?

Since it is an enterprise app, the iOS app has to be trusted by Apple for users to use it. I don't want the user to trust the app manually by going to settings.

Answer (score 0):

On ANdroid you can't silently install it.  You can download it and attempt to install it, which will prompt the user for permission.  To silently install, you'd need to be a system app with the appropriate permission.  Which means you'd need rooted devices, which more or less means devices you guys but and maintain.  But if that's a viable path you should check out device ownership policies and the amount of control you have that way.

Comment: What about iOS?

Comment: No clue.  If you gave me a choice between programming for iOS and have the skin flayed off my body, I'd pick the second.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Gabe, what you can do is, you can have your basic app installed on the device and then request request to install further content.